# Can not deploy my rails app to heroku after getting asset not present in asset pipeline error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

My app works fine on my localhost but now am trying to deploy it to heroku and it says:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

**Log file:**

```
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150511+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:32:05.150434 #4] FATAL -- : [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]   
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150586+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:32:05.150519 #4] FATAL -- : [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "landingherodrink.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150803+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:32:05.150736 #4] FATAL -- : [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     10:                 </div>
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150806+00:00 app[web.1]: [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     11:         </div>
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150806+00:00 app[web.1]: [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     12:         <div id="landingherodrink">
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150808+00:00 app[web.1]: [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     13:                 <%= image_tag("landingherodrink.jpeg") %>
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150808+00:00 app[web.1]: [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     14:         </div>
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150809+00:00 app[web.1]: [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     15:         <%= render 'footermenu/footermenu' %>      
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150809+00:00 app[web.1]: [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]     16: </body>
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150867+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:32:05.150807 #4] FATAL -- : [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd]   
2017-07-28T06:32:05.150971+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:32:05.150889 #4] FATAL -- : [333bb637-4f97-41fa-8b90-60452df2b4fd] app/views/landingpage/index.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_landingpage_index_html_erb__2117924159609624554_32934860'
2017-07-28T06:43:04.237065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thawing-cliffs-75380.herokuapp.com request_id=d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635 fwd="207.38.188.8" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2017-07-28T06:43:04.231745+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.231639 #4]  INFO -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635] Started GET "/" for 207.38.188.8 at 2017-07-28 06:43:04 +0000
2017-07-28T06:43:04.232703+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.232613 #4]  INFO -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635] Processing by LandingpageController#index as HTML
2017-07-28T06:43:04.233549+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.233492 #4]  INFO -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]   Rendering landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-07-28T06:43:04.234214+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.234157 #4]  INFO -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]   Rendered navmain/_navmain.html.erb (0.4ms)
2017-07-28T06:43:04.235218+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.235161 #4]  INFO -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]   Rendered landingpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
2017-07-28T06:43:04.235358+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.235306 #4]  INFO -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2017-07-28T06:43:04.235988+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.235934 #4] FATAL -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]   
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236030+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.235987 #4] FATAL -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "landingherodrink.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236172+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.236123 #4] FATAL -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     10:                 </div>
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236174+00:00 app[web.1]: [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     11:         </div>
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236174+00:00 app[web.1]: [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     12:         <div id="landingherodrink">
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236175+00:00 app[web.1]: [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     13:                 <%= image_tag("landingherodrink.jpeg") %>
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236176+00:00 app[web.1]: [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     14:         </div>
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236176+00:00 app[web.1]: [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     15:         <%= render 'footermenu/footermenu' %>      
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236177+00:00 app[web.1]: [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]     16: </body>
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236210+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.236170 #4] FATAL -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635]   
2017-07-28T06:43:04.236253+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-07-28T06:43:04.236214 #4] FATAL -- : [d535ef51-8a33-41dc-b820-50e9a43ca635] app/views/landingpage/index.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_landingpage_index_html_erb__2117924159609624554_32934860'
2017-07-28T06:43:04.335568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thawing-cliffs-75380.herokuapp.com request_id=00e2db2c-310c-48a1-88f9-7e3e9e302a4d fwd="207.38.188.8" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
```

It also shows:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "landingherodrink.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.).
```

It is my hero image and it is located at `assets/images/`

Comment: Did you configure your application to serve your static assets ? More on this here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: hello, I just did that by adding `config.assets.serve_static_files = true` on my config/application.rb and it didnt work, same error. Also tried `rails_serve_static_assets` gem and getting the same error.

Comment: I added a gem file `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` and also changed the hero picture and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @craftdeer it's no more needed in rails 5 Apps.
https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-5

Comment: @MuhammadNasirShamshad Yes, but for anyone still experiencing this issue with new rails applications, assets must be referenced with their extensions! So 'landingherodrink.jpeg' not just 'landingherodrink'

Answer (score 27):

In **Rails 5+**, make sure you have specified the file extension.

Ie.:

```
<%= image_tag 'logo.jpg' %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= image_tag 'logo' %>
```

Comment: The error pasted above clearly shows the extension is there
`ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "landingherodrink.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline.).`

I'm having this issue currently. Trying to find out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a bit too late but just had the same issue and fixed it just by changing my image extension from .jpeg to .jpg and of course changing it also in the code.

Comment: This worked for me. Does anybody have an explanation?

Comment: Worked for me too for absolutely no reason. This is so dumb that this was the issue. Even have jpg and jpeg set as asset extensions in webpacker.